# WordPress ACF Taxonomy (select Multiple) Field not pulling term name

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms, acfpro

Using WordPress, I have a CPT with a custom taxonomy (portfolio_categories).
I have set up an ACF Taxonomy (multiple select) field so that the user can select with portfolio categories to display (image, name, link..).

I have managed to pull the image and the link, but for some reason, the name of the category is not pulling through. When I `var_dump($term->name);` it returns `NULL`.

I'm very confused and tried a number of different code snippets from various forum posts, but nothing seems to work.

**Here is my template code:**

```html
<?php // portfolio categories block
  if( get_row_layout() == 'portfolio_categories_layout' ):
 ?>
  <section class="portfolio-categories">
    <?php
      $terms = get_sub_field('portfolio_categories_layout_select', $post->ID);
      if( $terms ):
    ?>
      <ul class="category-list">
        <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>
          <li class="category-item">
            <div class="image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($term); ?>');"></div>

            <div class="overlay"></div>

            <div class="content">
              <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
              <h2><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?></h2>

              <a class="button button-primary" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ); ?>">View</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>

    <?php endif; ?>
  </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `<?php echo $term[0]->name; ?>`

Comment: Thanks Matt, but that doesn't work either. When I turn DEBUG on, I get the following error: `Notice: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\project-name\wp-content\themes\theme-name\_templates\home-flex.php on line 92` - which is where I' trying to output the name...?

Comment: My bad, It's because I had the ACF taxonomy set as ID not an object. Thanks anyway Matt.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your Taxonomy 'return value' set to 'term object', and not 'term ID'.